# Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile not working YII?

Tags: php, yii

I have put these lines in my testLayout.php in views/layouts.
I also put some jquery in **yii\framework\web\js\source** to resolve conflicts(as they were creating conflict) and create  jquery entry in packages.php file.

It is working very perfect on my local machine (window 7). (can see script registration in view page source)

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('custom');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('foundationmin');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('app')

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('phoneIcs');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('phoneMask');
```

But when I uploaded my project to linux server and give permission #777 to assets folder. The CSS and jquery are not working.When I look it in page source ,I did not find any script register line.

I dont know What might be the problem.?

Answer (score 1):

Linux and Windows operating systems has difference in path separators: "/" for *nix and "\" for win, please check for slashes in your config for coreScripts paths.